# Existe alguma maneira de usar script como arquivos de configuração no python?

Tags: python, configuração

No PHP, podemos utilizar um script PHP para apenas retornar valores, o que é muito útil para criar arquivos de configurações para uma aplicação.

Exemplo `DB.php`

```
return array(
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'username' => 'username',
  ...
);
```

`index.php`

```
$config = include 'DB.php';

print_r($config); 

// Retorna o array contendo os valores retornados em "DB.php"
```

Ao tentar "imitar" isso em `Python`, não obtive êxito, pois me gerou um erro.

Exemplo `db.py`

```
return [
    1, 2, 3
]
```

Resultado:

> 'return' outside function

Nesse caso, se eu quissesse carregar um arquivo em `python`, apenas para fins de retorno de dados para configuração, como eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. A maneira mais difundida disso é fazer como o framework Django [faz](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/): Criando um arquivo (settings.py, por exemplo) e importando-o em outro módulo. Veja:

```
.
├── main.py
├── config.py
├── __init__.py
├── foo
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── ...
```

Então, se nosso módulo de configurações `config.py` fosse parecido com isso:

```
APPNAME = "Foo"
# server
SERVER = {
  "host": "1217.0.0.1",
  "port": 8980,
}
```

Então você poderia importar em main.py ou em qualquer outro módulo o namespace do arquivo de configurações, dessa forma:

```
# current mod: main.py

import config

xpto_connect(config.SERVER["host"], config.SERVER["port"])
```

Ou ainda importar partes do arquivo de configurações, somente as que você precisa:

```
# current mod: main.py

from config import SERVER, APPNAME

xpto_connect(SERVER["host"], SERVER["port"])
```

Como você pode ver, é extremamente fácil e me parece bem melhor que o modo que o PHP faz. ;)

Também, a instrução **return** somente pode ser usada na definição e escopo de função, por isso você está recebendo um erro.

### Nota

Diferentemente de PHP, você deve ter um arquivo chamado `__init__.py` ao lado do arquivo (mesmo nível no diretório) que você quer importar (que seria include, em PHP). Esse arquivo pode ser vazio.

Comment: Pensando bem na sua resposta, até parece com o jeito que é feito no Django

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com essa [resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5055466/3096922), creio que uma boa solução seria utilizar um arquivo `json` e analisá-lo pelo `python`.

Isso pode ser feito através do módulo `json`.

Exemplo JSON:

```
{
   "version" : "2.1",
}
```

Exemplo Python:

```
import json

config = json.load(open('composer.json'))

print(config['version']) # Imprime "2.1"
```

Comment: Acho que esse exemplo está misturado entre JavaScript e Python ;)

Comment: Eu estava me referindo à `var` e o comentário precedido por `//` ao invés de `#` (antes de você corrigir; agora está correto). Mas dá pra entender a sua sugestão sem problema.

Comment: Ok, @sergiopereira. não tem isso em `python` :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu não conheço uma maneira de fazer idêntica ao PHP, usando imports diretamente. Mas dá sim para usar um arquivo .py para configuração se você criar alguma convenção.

Por exemplo:

```
# em config/db.py
config = {
    'hostname': 'localhost',
    'port': 1234
}

# em seu script principal
db_config_file = 'config/db.py'
db_cfg = dict()
with open(db_config_file) as config_file:
    exec(compile(config_file.read(), db_config_file, 'exec'), db_cfg)
print db_cfg['config']
```

A convenção que usei é que o arquivo de configuração precisa definir uma variável `config`. Se você utilizar alguma convenção semelhante e aplicá-la para todos seus arquivos de configuração, você pode então colocar essa lógica de ler o arquivo em uma função utilitária.